# Light only one object

Tags: texturing, light

I'm trying to light only one object at my scenes, but with not sucess.
Would like to put light only at people and not at background. Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: I guess you can only do it with the Compositor, no?

Comment: How can I do it? I'm noob at blender yet haha

Comment: you need to check some tutorials about the Compositor, a bit tedious if you're new at Blender but maybe there's another way around

Comment: Oh thank you, I'll check out

Comment: try to find a tuto for 2.8 because the layer system has a bit changed since

Comment: Thank you I found it